# Find a word in a string python using regex or other methods

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to go through an array of words and check if they exist in a string. I understand there are many options for doing this such as using re.search but I need to differ between some words (ie. Java vs Javascript)

An example:

```
import re

s = 'Some types (python, c++, java, javascript) are examples of programming.'
words = ['python', 'java', 'c++', 'javascript', 'programming']

for w in words:
    p = re.search(w, s)
    print(p)

>><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(12, 18), match='python'>
>><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 24), match='java'>
>><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 30), match='javascript'>
>><_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(48, 59), match='programming'>
```

The above works to an extent but matches Java with Javascript.

EDIT: Here was my solution

```
for w in words:
        regexPart1 = r"\s"
        regexPart2 = r"(?:!+|,|\.|\·|;|:|\(|\)|\"|\?+)?\s"
        p = re.compile(regexPart1 + re.escape(w) + regexPart2 , re.IGNORECASE)
        result = p.search(s)
```

Comment: Figure out what should delimit your words (spaces? punctuation?), and then put the appropriate [lookbehinds/lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) around the patterns in your `words` list. For spaces, `\s`; for punctuation, a suitably-chosen `[]` character class.

Comment: You just need a `\b` word boundary: `p = re.search(r'\b' + w + r'\b', s)`

Comment: My delimeter would differ as my string will change. I need to check for all different types of special characters, the above is just an example of a string i may encounter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add word boundary marks to you regular expressions, say `r'/bjavascript/b'` in place of merely `'javascript'`. (Note also that `+` should be escaped in `c++` )

Also, iteration over words to match lacks potential efficiency of a compiled regexp. It may be better to combine the regexps into one:

```
w = r'\b(?:python|java|c\+\+|javascript|programming)\b'
re.search(w,s)
```